# How to snoop a virtually-addressed cache using a physical address

Tags: caching, x86, intel, cpu-architecture, virtual-memory

What are the options in which one can snoop a virtually addressed L1 using a given physical address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least three methods exist for snooping a virtually address L1 cache using physical addresses.

Perhaps the most obvious is to use an inclusive L2 cache addressed by physical addresses and including information about which set and way the block occupies (if it is in L1). The inclusion property only needs to apply to tags, for example, providing twice as many ways of associativity in tags as in blocks of data from memory. This can result in a miss in L2 requiring an eviction of an L1 cache line when L2 associativity is insufficient to handle all the blocks in L1 that map to a given index. Such evictions are generally rare given typical L2 capacity and associativity.

(Given 4 KiB pages, in a 32 KiB L1 a particular physical address can map to 8 different places using simple modulo indexing — skewed associativity complicates matters — so an inclusive 4-way associative physically-addressed L2 could not guarantee that such back invalidations would not occur, though an 8-way L2 could. Since spatial locality is common and L2 caches are relatively large, conflict issues are not as common as one would expect with random access patterns. Striding by a multiple of the page size would maximize such conflicts.)

A second method is closely related to the first is to replicate the tags in a physically addressed structure. (If this structure is associated with the L2, it might be considered a version of a tag-inclusive L2.) This allows the processor to access the cache using virtual addresses while snoops use physical addresses. The physically addressed tag store might need to have relatively high associaitivity, but since snoops are less common than processor cache accesses the probes can be done more slowly to save power (and area).

(In theory, this secondary tag store could be filter, e.g., using partial tags, which would typically indicate a snoop miss and typically limit the possibilities to one. With only one virtual tag in L1 to check occasionally, the performance loss from snooping accessing the virtually indexed L1 tags and using a TLB for translation may be acceptable. While a snoop could, in principle, retrieve all the possible virtual tags matching the physical address and translate and check them, this would typically be unacceptable overhead. For a direct-mapped L1 no larger than the page size, this might be acceptable, so this might count as another method. In addition, other filtering mechanisms might be proposed. Page coloring could reduce the number of addresses to be translated to the associativity of L1.)

A third method is to provide a reverse TLB which translates physical addresses to virtual addresses. (I seem to recall reading that a HP-RISC processor used this method.) A reverse TLB miss would indicate that the probed physical address is not in L1. This can introduce back-invalidations when a new translation must remove a translation that still has blocks in L1.

A virtually indexed and *physically tagged* L1 could simply probe additional possible ways on a snoop. This could interfere with the processor's access of L1, but in a scalar processor there might be sufficient data cache tag bandwidth to typically support access and snoop probes if only one or two virtual address indexing bits do not match the physical address bits then only two or four probes would be required. (Extra tag bandwidth provided for snooping could also be used for software prefetches and to allow tag-data sequential access for saving power when more access are ready to probe the cache than are supported by the data paths.)